# Line break in R plot legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I create many plots in R with data input from another script that are held in a separate variable each. I put the variables in a string and force a line break with `\n`. This works as intended, but the legend is not justified at all. `xjust` and `yjust` seem to not do anything. Also, when placing the legend e.g. in bottomright, it stretches beyond the margin of the plot. Any idea how I can properly place my legend justified at the corner of a plot?

Here a reproducible code snippet:

```
plot(c(0,3), c(0,3), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y")

a <- 2.3456
b <- 3.4567
c <- 4.5678
d <- 5.6789

Corner_text <- function(text, location = "bottomright"){
  legend(location, legend = text, bty = "o", pch = NA, cex = 0.5, xjust = 0) 
}
Corner_text(sprintf("a = %3.2f m\n b = %3.2f N/m\UB2\n c = %3.2f deg\n d = %3.2f perc", a, b, c, d))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`legend` is usually used to explain what the `points` or `lines` (and the different colors) represent. Therefore, inside the legend box (`bty`) there is a space where the lines/points are supposed to be. This probably explains why you think your text is not left-justified (you also have a problem of space after your line-break (`\n`): if you put a space after a line-break, it will be your first character on the next line, hence the text does not appear justified).

In your example, you don't have lines or points to explain, hence, I would use `text` rather than `legend`.
To know where "bottomright" is on your axes, you can use the graphical parameters `par("xaxp")` and `par("yaxp")` (it gives you the values of first and last ticks and the number of ticks on your axis).
On the x-axis, from the last tick, you need to shift left to have space for the widest line.

In `R code`, it gives:

```
# your plot
plot(c(0,3), c(0,3), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y")

# your string (without the extra spaces)
text_to_put <- sprintf("a = %3.2f m\nb = %3.2f N/m\UB2\nc = %3.2f deg\nd = %3.2f perc", a, b, c, d)

# the width of widest line
max_str <- max(strwidth(strsplit(text_to_put, "\n")[[1]]))

# put the text
text(x=par("xaxp")[2]-max_str, y=par("yaxp")[1], labels=text_to_put, adj=c(0, 0))

# if really you need the box (here par("usr") is used to know the extreme values on both axes)
x_offset <- par("xaxp")[1]-par("usr")[1]
y_offset <- par("yaxp")[1]-par("usr")[3]
segments(rep(par("xaxp")[2]-max_str-x_offset, 2), c(par("usr")[3], par("yaxp")[1]+strheight(text_to_put)+y_offset), c(par("xaxp")[2]-max_str-x_offset, par("usr")[2]), rep(par("yaxp")[1]+strheight(text_to_put)+y_offset, 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An example on how to do this using `ggplot2`, where legend creation is automatic when you map a variable in `aes`:

```
library(ggplot2)
units <- c('m', 'N/m\UB2', 'deg', 'perc')
p <- ggplot() + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1:4, color = letters[1:4])) +   #simple example
  scale_color_discrete(name = 'legend title',
                       breaks = letters[1:4],
                       labels = paste(letters[1:4], '=', c(a, b, c, d), units))
```

[image]

Or inside the plot:

```
p + theme(legend.position = c(1, 0), legend.justification = c(1, 0))
```

[image]

Or closer to your easthetic:

```
p + guides(col = guide_legend(keywidth = 0, override.aes = list(alpha = 0))) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = c(1, 0), legend.justification = c(1, 0),
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black'))
```

[image]